# Automatic commit/revision number in a php file or txt file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, revision

I am using: TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN Server

I would like if there is a way to automaticly include the revision number in a file.

All the things I found here were really unclear on how to do it, I am a beginner with SVN so.

Is there a way? And is there an easy guide or something for?

EDIT:
I would like the following: in a PHP file the current revision number. So if I commit to version 7, in the PHP file would stand 7. However, I could just do the same in a TXT file. Just the number, and then include it in the PHP.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed usage example? When do you want the revision number saved? Should the file be included in the commit? Do you want only the last revision or all revisions so far?

Comment: I would like the following: in a PHP file the current revision number. So if I commit to version 7, in the PHP file would stand 7. However, I could just do the same in a TXT file. Just the number, and then include it in the PHP.

Comment: Do you want the current (last changed) revision number of each file stored in the file, or the current revision of your "project"? The former is very easy, the latter was answered by @orbrey.

Comment: @MaartenMol96 You should update your question to include the additional information, not comment on it :) It makes it easier for others who come along later to see what the question was about without reading through all the comments.

Comment: @d-Pixie You mean like this?

Comment: @MaartenMol96 Yes, that is better :) You could also just update the question text itself, skipping the EDIT: section. Your question is not a monument, it's a tool. If changing it will help you and others get better answers you should change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SubWCRev program that comes with Tortoise to do this - the official page is here: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html

I've found if you navigate to a working copy folder in the windows command prompt and run `SubWCRev . > version.txt` you'll get the following in the version.txt file:

```
SubWCRev: 'C:\Users\User\SVN\repo1'
Last committed at revision X
Updated to revision Y
Local modifications found
Unversioned items found
```

Hope that gets you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking for is Subversion keyword substitution. That is, you include a comment in your PHP code like this:

```
# Revision     $Revision$
```

That breaks down to:

```
# marks the line as an inline comment
"Revision" -- a human-readable comment; may be anything you want
$Revision$ -- a keyword anchor
```

Once you commit the file with keyword anchors, whenever you retrieve the file from Subversion it will auto-fill those anchors. Revision number is just one of several such anchors available. For further details you can review the [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) section of the handy Red Bean book or [Part 5: Instrumenting Files with Version Information](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tortoisesvn-and-subversion-cookbook-part-5-instrumenting-files-with-version-information/) of my **TortoiseSVN/Subversion Cookbook**, which provides even more detail.